# Android layout manager available for Netbeans 6.8

Tags: android, netbeans, layout

I just Installed android 2.2 as a NetBeans 6.8 plugin, it works but I'm missing some tools like the layout ui manager, ïs this a ide specific tool or tis available for all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/). You can design your ui and it generates the xml files.

Comment: I have but tried but I but not sure haw to use. Because I keep draging the buttons and the won't stay